Conditionally updating a target in a Makefile
I have a tool that I use to generate C++ header files as part of the build. I only want to write out the generated headers if they changed from what is already on disk so that I don't trigger a rebuild of the object files that depend on those headers. I'm trying to do this with GNU Make. My problem is, because of the conditional write, I end up in a situation where the prerequisites are always newer than the target.
Here's a simplified example of my code:
$(TMP_GENERATED_FILE): $(SCRIPT_INPUT_FILES)
    $(SCRIPT) $< -o $@


$(GENERATED_FILE): $(TMP_GENERATED_FILE)
    cmp -s "$<" "$@" || cp -f "$<" "$@"

# Other rules for the .o files which depend on $(GENERATED_FILE)

The problem is $(TMP_GENERATED_FILE) will almost always be newer than $(GENERATED_FILE) because I only write out $(GENERATED_FILE) if it differs from $(TMP_GENERATED_FILE). This means the recipe for $(GENERATED_FILE) executes on every build. Is there any way to avoid this? The desired state is the subsequent runs of make would do nothing if nothing changed.
Edit: One other attempt was the following:
$(TEMP_GENERATED_FILE): $(SCRIPT_INPUT_FILES)
    $(SCRIPT) $< -o $@

# Get make to reread the Makefile after generating $(TEMP_GENERATED_FILE) so that the condition below works correctly
.PHONY: run_script
run_script: $(TEMP_GENERATED_FILE)
-include run_script

ifeq ($(shell cmp -s "$(TEMP_GENERATED_FILE)" "$(GENERATED_FILE)" && echo identical || echo different), different)
    $(GENERATED_FILE): $(TMP_GENERATED_FILE)
        cp -f "$<" "$@"
endif

but it seems like I run into the issue described here: " To avoid this make will not attempt to remake makefiles which are marked phony"

Remove cmp from the recipe. Why do you have a temporary file? Why not generate file directly?

If I do that, then the object files will rebuild even if the generated header didn’t change from the one that existed previously. That’s what I was trying to avoid.

No, make does a strict timestamp check. If any of prerequisite newer - run the recipe. If target is newer than all prerequisites - skip. You have a mistake in some other parts of your build scripts.

Imagine $(SCRIPT_INPUT_FILES) changes, then make will rebuild $(TMP_GENERATED_FILE). All good so far. But, imagine $(SCRIPT) $< -o $@ doesn't actually change the contents of $(TMP_GENERATED_FILE). Well, the timestamp is still updated which means the .o would also rebuild without the cmp check. I only want the rebuild to happen if the file contents of the generated file actually changed.

You are making assumption, that $(SCRIPT) $< -o $@ is run every time. It is not. It runs only if one of the file in $(SCRIPT_INPUT_FILES) is newer than $(TMP_GENERATED_FILE). Check, maybe one of these source files are made in the future?

Say that $(SCRIPT_INPUT_FILES) is foo.txt. If I add a bunch of whitespace to foo.txt, and pass it to $(SCRIPT), the output doesn't change.

Assuming, your script ignores these extra white spaces - yes the generated file will be the same as in previous version by contents. But your foo.txt will still be updated, therefore your foo.h supposed to be updated to the current version of foo.txt.

The short answer is there's no straightforward way to avoid it.
All versions of make use the fileystem as their "database" tracking what files are out of date or not.  In particular they use the modification time of files to detect when something is out of date.
You can prevent make from rebuilding things that depend on the GENERATED_FILE by not updating the modification time of the GENERATED_FILE.  But if you don't update the modification time of the GENERATED_FILE then the next time you run make it will still be out of date with respect to its prerequisites.
There's no way to change this algorithm.
The only way to avoid re-running the cmp recipe would be, if you discover that the GENERATED_FILE doesn't need to be rebuilt, to reset the timestamps of your prerequisites (e.g., TMP_GENERATED_FILE and all the SCRIPT_INPUT_FILES) so they were older than GENERATED_FILE and the next time you run make it will not think they are outdated.
But, make is not the only tool that uses modification times of files for important decisions so that change could have other impacts.  I personally would not advise it, and instead just live with the extra cmp being run every time.  It's not much of a burden IMO.

Thanks. I was hoping there was some way to do it by taking advantage of Makefile rereading after "include" (updated my question with an example) but maybe not. The main reason for avoiding the cmp is that our company has some tools that do a make --dry-run to ensure targets are up-to-date before proceeding (which is broken by cmp running every time). Agree that it's not a big deal in general.

You can't avoid running cmp, at some point.  It seems your requirement is not that cmp is not run at all, but rather that it's not run as a "normal" recipe, is that correct?  It's possible something could be made to work.  I'd have to play with it.  It probably will come with other downsides (re-execing make is, itself, not cheap!  A lot more expensive than running cmp that's for sure)

Yes, that is correct. I agree that cmp has to run at some point and it does seem like the only way to possibly achieve what I am after is if cmp was run outside of a recipe.

You have too complicated build of the header. Here is a working example:
# makefile
all: hello

hello: hello.o
    gcc $^ -o $@

hello.o: hello.c hello.h
    gcc -c $< -o $@

hello.h: hello.h.in1 hello.h.in2
    cat $^ > $@

// hello.c
#include "hello.h"

int main() {
    fputs("hello\n", stdout);
    return 0;
}

// hello.h.in1
/* autogenerated header */

// hello.h.in2
#include <stdio.h>

Testing:
$ make
cat hello.h.in1 hello.h.in2 > hello.h
gcc -c hello.c -o hello.o
gcc hello.o -o hello
$ touch hello.h.in2
$ make
cat hello.h.in1 hello.h.in2 > hello.h
gcc -c hello.c -o hello.o
gcc hello.o -o hello
$ touch hello.c
$ make
gcc -c hello.c -o hello.o
gcc hello.o -o hello
$ make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.

Questions?

This does not address the question, which is about avoiding rebuilding the object file in the case that the header is out of date with respect to its prerequisites, but the generator script produces an identical header.  I am not at all convinced that that's a thing worth doing, but it is what the question asks.

Regarding " I am not at all convinced that that's a thing worth doing": The reality is that we generate hundreds of C++ headers as part of the build using a domain-specific language. The generated headers have potentially thousands of downstream clients and so avoiding unnecessary rebuilds would save a lot of time and resources.
